# How to generate alerts on lower timeframe from chart in pine v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to to get alerts every hour when this indicator is plotted on the 4h chart. It doesnt seem to be working. I want to do this without using (syminfo.tickerid, "240"). I tried running it on h1 chart and request data from h4 timeframe but it gives random values.

Here is my code

```
//@version=5
indicator("H4 data with Alerts", overlay = true)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(0.5, 10)

alert_message = '{"dict": "H4", "H4_close": ' + str.tostring(close[1]) + ', "H4_ST": ' + str.tostring(supertrend[1]) + '}'

// Function to check if the current time matches any whole hour of the day
is_alert_time() =>
    timestamp("UTC", year, month, dayofmonth, hour, 0) == time

// Only trigger the alert if the current time matches any whole hour of the day
if is_alert_time()
    alert(message = alert_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript, your script is executed on each bar close.
So if you want alert every hour, you should use the 1 hour timeframe on your chart.

Also be careful with **time** as in pinescript, the time value returned are those of the provider of your data (Bitstamp, Quonda ...), not the time you choose on your chart.